# Как брать каждый n-ный элемент массива в Python

Tags: python, массивы

Есть массив **`lst`**, нужно каждый `n-ный` элемент массива отправить в другой массив. Пробовал делать так:

```
for i in range(0, len(lst[0])):
    if lst[0][i] % 10 = 0 then new_list.append(lst[0][i])
```

Использую `lst[0][i]` потому что это массив с одной строкой, в этой строке все элементы.

Но выдает ошибку `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: `lst[::n]` - почитайте о `slice` операциях для списков в Python

Comment: Ну так в питоне нету никакого `then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шаг цикла берётся таким образом:

```
for i in range(0, 11, 2):, где 2 - шаг цикла
    print(i)
```

Но если вы просто хотите создать новый массив, то я предлагаю вам следующую форму записи, которая решает вашу задачу, применимую и к строкам, и к массивам:

```
s = 'somestring'
s = s[::2] # эквивалентно [0::2]

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
lst = lst[::2] #[стартовый индекс:конечный индекс:шаг]
               # если ничего не указано, то [0:-1:1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Берём срез всех элементов списка `a` с шагом `n`.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
n = int(input())
b = a[::n]
print(b)
```